# No audio through HDMI - nvidia gfx

Tags: drivers, nvidia, hdmi

I have read a lot of posts about this, mainly it is people with ATI cards or people that havnt got the option to choose HDMI audio. But it just ain't my problem, afaik.

I have installed my Graphics card, and hooked up my old labtop to the TV as a media center, videofeed is going through nicely. But the sound is lacking, even though the HDMI output is selected, then it stills outputs the sound through the labtop.
I have got a nvidia 9500M(as far as i remember) updated the drivers like [this](http://falkvinge.net/2013/02/15/how-to-install-nvidia-drivers-in-ubuntu-12-10-quantal/)

At the bottom you will see an image with my option to select HDMI, but no mode or a like is available but the option is there.

Hopes someone can help me. Thanks

EDIT 1:
Okay so have tried what was written, running alsamixer (really not sure what I can do within it though there is nothing directly mentioned as HDMI, could not turn up volume for S/PDIF it was locked on 00, screenshot at the bottom.)
Also I installed pavucontrol, and tried it, did nothing.

What I find really weird is that when i switch from speakers to HDMI nothing happens, I still hear sound through the speakers, but if I change to S/PDIF then sound stops, also if switched to HDMI again. Until it has been switched back to speakers.

Image 1(option to choose HDMI):
[image: image 1]

Image 2(alsamixer):

[image: Image2 of alsamixer]

Comment: Have you tried running `alsamixer`, to ensure that the HDMI on the video card isn't muted? I also had to run `pavucontrol` and select HDMI as the output device, but I'm using Xubuntu, not regular Ubuntu, so I don't know if the same applies...

Comment: @Ash You can see result and maybe give some more advice?

Comment: In alsamixer, press F6 and see if there's another device on the list other than the one above -- that may be your GPU (the default one is normally the onboard, but I'm not sure, since it says nVidia above...)

Answer (score 0):

I recall having a similar problem some time ago. I installed Pulseaudio Volume Controller and used that to select the HDMI output under the configuration tab. Do

```
sudo apt-get install pulseaudio
```

I'm not sure this will work but it may be worth a try!